# LinkageError during classloader programming

Tags: java, classloader

I have some different web service clients which use coinciding classes with same name and same package but slightly different implementation, implemented by third party.

All these clients are called from my application, so since Weblogic classloder loads just one of those common classes, I get errors on runtime during web service response deserialization.

So I create a child classloader and load specific WS client at application startup, store class types in static fields and call WS with reflection using those pre-prepared classes.

```
URL wsclientJarURL = new URL(wsclientJarPathStr);
List<URL> jarURLList = Arrays.asList(wsclientJarURL);

//loads wsclient from childClassLoader, 
//rest of axis, httpCommons, commonsLogging is used from parentClassLoader
ParentLastURLClassLoader childClassLoader = new ParentLastURLClassLoader(jarURLList);

//Loading all classes in a jar
String className = null;
JarEntry je = null;
JarFile wsClientJarFile = new JarFile(wsclientJarPathStr.replaceAll("file:", ""));
Enumeration<JarEntry> e = wsClientJarFile.entries();                

while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
    je = e.nextElement();
    if(je.isDirectory() || !je.getName().endsWith(".class")){
        continue;
    }

    // -6 because of .class
    className = je.getName().substring(0,je.getName().length()-6);
    className = className.replace('/', '.');
    childClassLoader.loadClass(className);
}

XXXXTypeClass = Class.forName ("com.aaa.bbb.XXXXType", true, childClassLoader);
YYYYTypeClass= Class.forName ("com.aaa.bbb.YYYYType", true, childClassLoader);
```

Unfortunately I get the error below, although I don't load common libraries like "javax.xml" and lookup them from parentClassloader.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Class javax/xml/rpc/Call violates loader constraints
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at xxx.yyy.classloader.ParentLastURLClassLoader$ChildURLClassLoader.findClass(ParentLastURLClassLoader.java:59)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at xxx.yyy.Client.<init>(Client.java:31)
        ... 115 more
```

Checked for version differences for RPC library in all client WS used at compile time. But all has same versions as below.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Weblogic is instructed to use libraries in war (jaxrpc-api-1.1) instead of its own libraries when resolving/linking classes via weblogic.xml

```
<prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

Any idea for cause of problem and how to fix it?